# Angular js with MVC: locationProvider.html5Mode(true) Links Does Not Work, becuse it want to get controller and action from Server

Tags: angularjs, location-provider

When using angular js routing by default add # after end of location link, and after # any other is the compiled by angular js,
if I want to not show # I can use `locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`
after route process for example my links in location convert from
`http://example.com/#Name` to `http://example.com/Name`
now if I create a link using `<a href='/name'>test</a>` it is works.
but when I use `http://example.com/Name` in address bar and enter, it is not works, and I get error about not found controller named `Name` controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you directly type the url in the browser, it makes a server request. In HTML 5 mode depending upon the server technology you would have to do url rewrite. This is what the documentation on location https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/guide/$location has to say.

> **Server side**
>
> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side,
>   basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your
>   application (e.g. index.html)